# Error 500 en localhost

Tags: laravel, api, xampp, guzzle, laragon

Estoy trabajando con laravel 8 una aplicación que consume recursos de una API hecha en laravel 5.6; la cuestión radica en que al hacer el login con JWT me regresa el token correctamente, pero si necesito hacer otra petición (POST, GET, etc) me lanza un error 500 Internal ServerError y aunque haga debug no encuentro la razon por la cual me esta retornando el error en cualquier ruta excepto el login.

Cliente:

```
     $cliente = new Client([
'base_uri' => $url,
'headers' => ['origin' => $url, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json']
]);
```

Petición de quiebre:

```
public function logout() : array{
 
 try{
 $response = $cliente->post("{$base_url}/auth/logout",[
 'headers' => [
 'Authorization' => "Bearer {$token}",
 'Accept' => 'application/json'
 ],
 ]);
 return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(),true);
 }catch(ServerException $e){
 dd($e);
 }
 }
```

Ya revise rutas, .env, configuracion (utilizo XAMPP) y parece que todo esta en orden con los archivos del servidor donde consumo la API; una de las cosas mas extrañas es que en otra maquina en local SI funciona (LARAGON).

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos.

Comment: Error 500 es un error del Servidor, puedes buscar el log de php y Apache y verificar

Comment: tambien valida la version de php que corre los dos stack...